# Using a C function to populate a QByteArray

Tags: c++, c, qt

I'm curious as to whether it is safe to pass the data pointer of a `QByteArray` that has been properly resized, to a c function that will populate the memory within it.

I am thinking that it shouldn't be a problem, but I feel kinda gross doing it.

```
SpeexBits bits;
void *dec_state;
int bufferPosition = 0;
const int SAMPLES_PER_SEC = 32000;
const int BUFFER_LEN_SECONDS = 5;
const int FRAME_SIZE_BYTES = SAMPLES_PER_SEC / (1000 / 20) * sizeof(int16_t);

QByteArray outBuf;
outBuf.resize(SAMPLES_PER_SEC * sizeof(int16_t) * BUFFER_LEN_SECONDS);

...

speex_bits_read_from(&bits, msg->payload, msg->size);
speex_decode_int(dec_state, &bits, outBuf.data() + bufferPosition);
bufferPosition += FRAME_SIZE_BYTES;

...

<playback>
```

Though I think this should work, it doesn't feel right, however, I don't want to make multiple copies of the data for no other reason than to populate the `QByteArray` with an insert method call. So I guess my question is, can I safely do this? Is this the recommended way to populate a `QByteArray` from a function? Is there a better way that doesn't require multiple copies of the data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly safe, `QByteArray` has two methods to get the data, `constData()` and `data()` you can pass data and treat it as a `char *` buffer, and use it as one in  a c function without problem.

The same problems that would occur in the case of buffer overflow and such, will occur so you must be as careful as you would be in c.